# Find range of column, given column number VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

How would I find and store a range object for an entire column, given the column number?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Columns` property

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns(12) ' for column 12
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub PickAColumn()
   Dim i As Long
   Dim MyColumn As Range
   i = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Column NUMBER ", Type:=1)
   Set MyColumn = Cells(1, i).EntireColumn

   MyColumn.Select
End Sub
```